# What's the meaning of 'challenge' in SASL

Tags: kerberos, sasl, gssapi

I'm reading the RFC 4422 document which detail described the SASL framework, but English is not my native language. I really can't understand what's the 'challenge' mean in SASL? The following content is extracted from the document: 
Where the mechanism specifies that the first data sent in the
   exchange is from the client to the server and this field is
   unavailable or unused, the client request is followed by an empty
   challenge.

```
  C: Request authentication exchange
  S: Empty Challenge
  C: Initial Response
  <additional challenge/response messages>
  S: Outcome of authentication exchange
```

'an empty challenge' is an empty request? or something else? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Challenge == "prove me you are who you are"

Comment: A non-empty challenge could be "OK, user X has a public key, so prove me you have the private key by decrypting this..."  i.e. a closed question. An empty challenge is more of an open question.